# Creating a mysql outfile with a timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create an outfile that has the current timestamp, but I'm not familiar enough with SQL syntax to do it.

```
"SELECT *FROM CUSTOMER INTO OUTFILE '/g/r.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Lets say that instead of outputting r.csv, I want to output the current time. How would I do that?

Comment: You Can't. The `into outfile` only accepts a filename, not an expression, so something like `into outfile concat('file', now())` won't work.

Comment: Well say that that this is a bash script, where I'm invoking the query. Could I possibly use a variable via bash to do this, via the 'date' command in bash?

Comment: sure, you could have bash create the query string and stuff a timestamp into the outfile name. you just can't have mysql do it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not very elegant, but you can do

`SELECT *, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS extract_dt FROM CUSTOMER INTO OUTFILE`

It will result in the same timestamp value being appended to the end of each row.   It's not very efficient, but there is no other way that I know of of including the extract time into an output file (other than to read the file creation date using a non-database utility).